# For loop using robot framework with 2 parameters

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, robotframework

I have two list variables `@{vinrange}` and `@{sg}` both with same dimensions of 4
[image]

I want to print into the `LOG` using the scalar `${VAR1}` for each value from the list variable `@{vinrange}` and print using a second scalar `${VAR2}` for each value from the list variable `@{sg}`

I have to assign both of them into the same loop, the `${VAR1}[1]` has worked for the `@{vinrange}`, however, I don't know how to do for the second list variable `@{sg}`.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `FOR` construct version precisely for this situation - to iterate over two lists simultaneously - that is with `IN ZIP`, [link to the documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-in-zip-loop) .
It expects two or more iterables (like lists), and on every iteration returns the values of each at the same index.

Note that it will stop at the shorter one's last element (e.g. if their lengths are different, it won't raise an exception, nor it will fully exhaust the longer list). So for your case:

```
FOR    ${vinrange_element}    ${sg element}    IN ZIP     ${vinrange}       ${sg}
     Log      ${vinrange element} 
     Log      ${sg element}
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to count your list by use **`Get Count`** than **`FOR LOOP`** and log by using Iterator ${i}.
Here sample for you

```
${length}=   Get Count   ${vinrange}
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE     1       ${length}
     Log      ${vinrange}[${i}]
     Log      ${sg}[${i}]
END
```

Answer (score 0):

A Generic Context of For Loop in robot framework is

```
FOR    ${item}    IN    @{ITEMS}
    ${item}    Arg2
END
```

Example-

```
FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    42
    1st arg    ${index}
END
```

Comment: I would argue on this; the first sample code will try to execute every list member as a keyword, passing "Arg2" as an argument - this better be a list of keywords, quite unorthodox. The second one will not iterate over a list, but will produce the numbers 0...41, and pass them as an argument to the keyword "1st arg".